# How to get a valid Access token from Firebase in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the library `angularfire2` to do the authentication.

I need to authenticate with a Token. How to generate a token to use in:

```
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    [...]
    this.angukarFireAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(TOKEN);
```

If I pass some value, I receive the error: `The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a custom token, you can the Firebase Admin SDK. The Admin Node.js SDK offers a `createCustomToken(uid, customClaims)` method to do so. You can then send the generated token to the client to `signInWithCustomToken`. Learn more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens